# Casperjs inspect a javascript Object

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

How can I inspect an object in a casperjs script ?

I tried `console.log(arguments)` but it only prints [object Arguments] or [object Object].

I would like to expect something like:
{
'firstparam': 'value'
...
}

Like in the Javascript console or in Node.js...

Maybe it's a Phantomjs question, I'm not sure...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I found it: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/debugging.html#dump-serialized-values-to-the-console

```
var utils = require('utils');

utils.dump({
    foo: {
        bar: 42
    },
});
```

Comment: I wonder how to use the phantom.js one, I know there must be something because when running on console (interactively) `var a = {a:[1]}; a` prints neatly

Comment: Just use standard `JSON.stringify()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify for a simple string read, e.g.

```
casper.test.comment(JSON.stringify(object));
```